# Better alternative to finding a value in array of arrays instead of using indices? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have JavaScript data that looks like this:

```
[
  ["firstName", "bob"],
  ["lastName", "smith"],
  ["address", "123 Main St]
]
```

The second values in each array (bob, smith, 123 main st) are entered from the user. I'm simply wanting to print the entered value. I know I can use indices (such as [0][1] to capture "bob") but is there a better way to do that? I know JavaScript objects have a .get() method where you can enter the key and have the value returned (such as .get("firstName") to return "bob"). Is there someway to do that with arrays?

Thanks!

Comment: what about [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)?

Comment: `const table = Object.fromEntries(myArray); console.log(table['firstName']);`, or maybe even create a `Map`.

Comment: That's an unusual structure. Would make more sense to use an object for each person

Comment: You said the second values are what the user entered. Why not store the entered data into an object in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

this way...
you may learn about [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const dataArr2 = 
  [ [ "firstName", "bob"]
  , [ "lastName", "smith"]
  , [ "address", "123 Main St"]
  ]
  
let obj = Object.fromEntries( dataArr2 )

console.log( obj.firstName ) // bob
console.log( obj.lastName )  // smith
console.log( obj.address )   // 123 Main St
```

Comment: out of curiosity, where does the formatting with comma at the beginning of the line come from? I can see the potential value of it showing clearly the indentation and array group, but I have never seen it before.

Comment: @asyncawait it is from me; I've written tons of lines of code forever and often forgot to put commas at the end of lines, now I'm sure I don't forget them, otherwise I'm using the Whitesmiths style too, for similar reasons, even if somes find it hard to accept that other can practice a different coding style than K&R

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do so. Please check the below given examples.

```js
const personArr = [
  ["firstName", "bob"],
  ["lastName", "smith"],
  ["address", "123 Main St"],
];

console.log(new Map(personArr));
console.log(Object.fromEntries(personArr));

function toObject(arr = []) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc[key] = value;
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
console.log(toObject(personArr));

const { firstName, lastName, address } = toObject(personArr);
console.log(firstName, lastName, address);
```